# Display 2 Partial Razor Views in main Index View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I'm having trouble rendering a 2nd partial view next to the first view after the user clicks on the hyperlink inside the table as shown in the images. When the user clicks the 2nd view does not render and the views disappear.

index.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using PracticeApp.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace PracticeApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public CompanyContext _context;

        public IndexModel(CompanyContext context) { _context = context; }

        public PartialViewResult OnPostDisplayDepartment(int value)
        {
            return Partial("_DisplayDepartmentPartial", _context.Departments.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == value).ToList());
        }

        public PartialViewResult OnPostDisplayEmployee(int value)
        {
            return Partial("_DisplayEmployeePartial", _context.Employees.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == value).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }

<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBox("TxtDepartment")
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="DepartmentSearch">Search</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<br />
<div id="DepartmentResult"></div>
<div id="EmployeeResult"></div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $("#DepartmentSearch").click(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/Index?handler=DisplayDepartment",
                type: "POST",
                data: { value: $("#TxtDepartment").val() },
                headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function(data) { $("#DepartmentResult").html(data); }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

_DisplayDepartmentPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Department>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <table style="border: 1px solid black">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">Department Results</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DepartmentId)
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DepartmentName)
                </td>
            </tr>

            @foreach (Models.Department item in Model)
             {
                <tr>
                    <td id="TxtEmployee" align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        <a id="EmployeeSearch" href="Index?handler=DisplayDepartment#">
                            @item.DepartmentId
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @item.DepartmentName
                    </td>
                </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
 }
else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $("#EmployeeSearch").click(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "Index?handler=DisplayDepartment",
                type: "POST",
                data: { value: $("#TxtEmployee").val() },
                headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function(data) { $("#EmployeeResult").html(data); }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

_DisplayEmployeePartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Employee>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <table style="border: 1px solid black">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">Employee Results</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DepartmentId)
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EmployeeName)
                </td>
            </tr>

            @foreach (Models.Employee item in Model)
             {
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @item.DepartmentId
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @item.EmployeeName
                    </td>
                </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
 }
else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}
```

[image: when user enters value in textbox and presses button]

[image: when user clicks on hyperlink inside table]

Comment: Pretty confident you don't need SQL Server experts for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial Views are not able to use the `@section` element by default.

Try removing the razor syntax around the script section and just use `<script></script>`.

If you want to use a tag to call js method, you should use `href="javascript:aa()"` and the passed value should be `$("#EmployeeSearch").text()`.
When you click on `a` tag you should call `DisplayEmployee`, not `DisplayDepartment`.

So your `_DisplayDepartmentPartial.cshtml` should look like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Department>
@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <table style="border: 1px solid black">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">Department Results</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Id)
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name)
                </td>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
             {
                <tr>
                    <td id="TxtEmployee" align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        <a id="EmployeeSearch" href="javascript:aa()">@item.Id</a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @item.Name
                    </td>
                </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
 }
else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}

    <script>
        $("#EmployeeSearch").click(function () {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "Index?handler=DisplayEmployee",
                type: "POST",
                data: { value: $("#EmployeeSearch").text() },
                headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function(data) { $("#EmployeeResult").html(data); }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Ty @Chen this works, one thing I found odd is if I remove the DepartmentId column and instead search by the Department Name, I get No Data message instead of the results

Comment: You need to change the logic in `index.cstml.cs`. The parameter is `string value`, sql should be `_context.Employees.Where(x => x.DepartmentName == value).ToList()`.

Comment: I tried that already and I still get no data, I even did a Rebuild Solution

Comment: Oh I get it, you should be `<a id="EmployeeSearch" href="javascript:aa()">@item.DepartmentName</a>`, don't wrap.

Comment: you are the best, it worked, so it's bad practice to wrap

Comment: did you get a chance to see question that i had?